# Scrolling with scroll wheel or trackpad doesn't work when connected to Ubuntu 22.10 via built in RDP Remote Desktop Protocol

Tags: mouse, remote-desktop, scrolling, rdp

I'm not able to scroll with a scroll wheel or trackpad on most apps when remoting into Ubuntu 22.04 or 22.10 using Ubuntu's built-in remote desktop protocol. Scrolling works fine when connected directly to Ubuntu, but if I use a separate computer to remote into Ubuntu, scrolling doesn't work. When connected to Ubuntu via RDP, scrolling works in the settings app, the files app, and text editor but doesn't work in the pre-installed Firefox app, or Google Chrome installed via .deb package. I have tried multiple mouses and three different computers running MacOS and Windows to remote into Ubuntu, all which have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2473. That bug is fixed in mutter-43.1.
It will take some weeks to a few months though until Ubuntu pushes the update.

Comment: Ohh thanks for the info! Do you know if there's any way to manually update this?